# How to embed a web conference room into web application?

Tags: flash, webcam, conference, video-conferencing, webinar

I would like someone's advice to find a solution for this situation.

Basically what I need is to have a permanent web conference room in my web application to handle remote interviews.

This means that any user of the web application can get access to the room and have an interview with another user of the same web application, I need only 2 connection at the same time.

I did a little research about this topic and I have found several different solutions but none of them, at least at first sight look simple to integrate.

-

For instance:
 http://open-tube.com/7-free-web-conferencing-tools/
 http://tomuse.com/top-10-free-web-conference-services/
 http://www.mikogo.com/
 http://www.onwebinar.com/
 http://demo.bigbluebutton.org/
 http://code.google.com/p/red5/

By the way I love open source, actually my application runs in a Debian server, but I really don't have any experience in installing media servers, etc, so I was thinking maybe to use an external service and embed it into my web application as it was hosted there, I know this solution might cost, but maybe for an quick solution can work for the moment.

I would like to keep it very simple, having video and audio is enough, I see these software handle presentations, dashboards, chats, multiple connections in the same room, etc, all of these is not needed at this time.

I offered to my boss the solution of having this interview over skype or google talk for instance, but he did not like the idea to make the users sign in these services just to have the remote interview.

The requirement is to let any user enter to the interview room, then have a web cam conference in the same web application.

I was wondering if someone can share his experience with me.

I'll appreciated very much.
Carlos Balderas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, after doing some research I have found that tinychat http://es.tinychat.com/ and tokbox http://www.tokbox.com/ (among others) have the functionality I was looking for.

IMHO, both look ok.

- tinychat looks very simple to implement.
- tokbox looks with a lot flexibility to program using their API. Although tinychat let you use their API too, I didn't find an easy way to access technical documentation, but it is very worth it to look at it.

Comment: This article contains more options. http://savedelete.com/top-10-best-free-chat-room-websites-to-know-strangers.html