# Web Conference without client

Tags: web, video-streaming, audio-streaming

What technologies are available to accomplish audio streaming between browsers without the need for additional software?

I have tried Lync Server which doesn't support audio/video, WebRTC which is not supposed by IE and now I am trying Silverlight but it's not really well at all.

Anyone else know of any other ways?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read here for starter: [How to embed a web conference room into web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5980870/how-to-embed-a-web-conference-room-into-web-application)

There are providers out there that will sort this out for you but if you want open source/free it is likely to be based on WebRTC.

You can also use Flash if you want browser coverage but providing code for that is beyond the scope of stackoverflow however Google can help you find a proper solution (you will most likely need a server like Wowza)